# Event from Netcat source doesn't go through Kafka channel

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, flume

I use a flume agent to collect external data via Flume agent. External data batch is almost 1MB per 10 seconds. I configured Flume agent as following.

```
# Flume agent configuration as /flume/conf/agent.conf
agent.sources = netcat-source
agent.channels = kafka-channel
agent.sinks = logger-sink

########################################
#   Netcat Source
########################################

agent.sources.netcat-source.type = netcat
agent.sources.netcat-source.bind = 0.0.0.0
agent.sources.netcat-source.port = 4141
agent.sources.netcat-source.max-line-length = 500000
agent.sources.netcat-source.channels = kafka-channel

########################################
#   Kafka Channel
########################################

agent.channels.kafka-channel.type =  org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
agent.channels.kafka-channel.brokerList = 10.212.136.108:9092,10.212.136.108:9092
agent.channels.kafka-channel.zookeeperConnect = 10.212.136.108:2181,10.212.136.108:2181/kafka
agent.channels.kafka-channel.topic = channel
agent.channels.kafka-channel.groupId = fcd-group


########################################
#   Logger Sink
########################################

agent.sinks.logger-sink.type = logger
agent.sinks.logger-sink.channel = kafka-channel
```

I activated the agent in following manner.

```
flume-ng agent -n agent -c /flume/conf -f /flume/conf/agent.conf
```

Unfortunately, it turned out that netcat source worked well and something went wrong with channel or sink. From resource monitor of Ubuntu, I can see the following performance. 
[Network performance. Blue curve indicates input while red one indicates output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nokk2.png)
Without other application running with network io, I'm sure this figure demonstrated what happened to my Flume agent.

I got nothing when I checked Kafka content in topic "channel" through console consumer. Also, when I checked *flume.log*, I only got Flume output of its status without data.

I had validated incoming data using

```
nc -lk 4141 >> my_data_check_file
```

What's wrong with my channel or sink？

P.S. Things went similarly tricky when I used memory channel, file channel.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, at last, I solved this problem by myself!

**The key point is the row delimeter '\n'.**

In Flume source code *NetcatSource.java*, we have a triky row like following

```
private int processEvents(CharBuffer buffer, Writer writer) throws IOException {
  int numProcessed = 0;

  boolean foundNewLine = true;
  while (foundNewLine) {
    foundNewLine = false;

    int limit = buffer.limit();
    for (int pos = buffer.position(); pos < limit; pos++) {
      if (buffer.get(pos) == '\n') {  
        // parse event body bytes out of CharBuffer
        buffer.limit(pos); // temporary limit
        ByteBuffer bytes = Charsets.UTF_8.encode(buffer);
        buffer.limit(limit); // restore limit
... ...
... ...
```

The code forces input data to end with '\n'. Otherwise, no events will be taken by channel. We can change this character as needed and put customized source into $FLUME_HOME/lib